# Show active Tab in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to show the active tab in an Angular app. The trouble is that the tab is located in a sub header where as the component which dictates which tab is active is in another location. My code will explain better.

*Sub header HTML*

```
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="action" > Contributions and savings </div>
  <div class="action"> Retirement strategy </div>
</div>
```

*Sub header TS*

```
ngOnInit() {
  localStorage.getItem('step');
}
```

*Component HTML*

```
<app-subheader></app-subheader>
```

*Component TS*

```
localStorage.setItem('step', JSON.stringify(this.step));
```

Now as "Step" is updated in localStorage, I need to check in the subheader.ts everytime the value changes so I can update the tab to show active css. Any ideas, I am stuck here. How can I check for when the value changes? NgOninit only does it once.

Comment: Please show the `subheader.ts` and the `component.html`

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I've added them but I don't have much there

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: I have got a bit further but need to now see when the value changes

Comment: @aviboy2006 I have made a simplified stackblitz here  https://angular-tqnq6b.stackblitz.io. Please see my updated question.

Comment: give code access also in stackblitz so i can edit and help you.

Comment: @aviboy2006 please try here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqnq6b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making active tab logic you can do this :

HTML:

```
<button (click) = "clickTab(1)" [ngClass]="{'active': step === 1}">ONE</button>
<button (click) = "clickTab(2)" [ngClass]="{'active':step === 2}">TWO</button>
```

TS :

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.step == 1;
    localStorage.setItem('step', JSON.stringify(this.step));
  }
  clickTab(stepValue){
    this.step = stepValue;
    localStorage.setItem('step', JSON.stringify(this.step));
  }
```

CSS:

```css
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

Here is the working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqnq6b

Answer (score 0):

- The above method is correct but the #stackblitz link is not clear, I have added the link as below
- Here is the working example:
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdw6sl

HTML:

```
<button [class]="btnActive === 'one' ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeBtn('one')">ONE</button>
<button [class]="btnActive === 'two' ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeBtn('two')">TWO</button>
<button [class]="btnActive === 'three' ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeBtn('three')">THREE</button>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
   background-color: red;
   color: #fff;
}
```

TS:

```
btnActive: string = 'one';

ngOnInit() {}

activeBtn(btnActive: string) {
   this.btnActive = btnActive;
}
```